# Insert a group of documents in MongoDB filtered by their existence

Tags: node.js, mongodb, insertion

My collection already has some documents, and I want to insert a group of new documents which contains both some has been existed in this collection and new ones.

I'm using the nodejs driver api, does it provide an api and option to fulfill this job or I should find the excited ones and filter them, then do the insertion?

Comment: Do you have an id external to node for each document that you can use to identify which documents already exist in the collection, e.g. a filename, record id, etc.? You need a unique key to query against that allows you to determine which documents are already in MongoDB. If you don't have a unique key, you have no way to determine reliably which documents already exist there. If you have a key, just query for all the keys, filter out the keys that exist in MongoDB already, and insert the others. Should be a fairly trivial function to write.

Comment: If you do have the `_id`'s, you can also use an [unordered insert](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/#perform-an-unordered-insert). Since `_id`'s should be unique, existing documents will fail to be saved (because the `_id` already exists) but new documents will be saved.